# How to download CSV file in Jmeter Scripting

Tags: jmeter, export-to-csv, mime, beanshell

[Jmeter has recorded only these(Please check the request in attached screenshot) parameters for downloading the csv from application to the local machine. But when i execute the script the file does not get download on my local.

There are no parameters in FileUpload tab as well.

Please help me out to record this request. Also let me know if any more info is needed to analyse the scenario] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn0dF.png)

[CSV gets downloaded on local on clicking the highlighted link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viLUg.png)

[This is the request and response headers recieved.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7AXC3.png)
.....................................................................

Save response to file listener Screenshot[png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McOsy.png)

BeanShell Code to delete file screenshot [png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3RCZ.png)

I am stuck with the attached error in the jmeter log [png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csxkT.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your request there are at least 2 parameter's i.e. **rid and pageQs** which needs to be co-related. Record and replay mostly never work and you need to co-relate the dynamic parameters. First, identify where there are getting generated then capture it and pass it to the subsequent request.

Try to record the request 2 times using a sniffing tool like Fiddler or Wireshark. Compare and check what values are changing in the request.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sunny. 
rid and PageQs both parameters are constant, as they always point to a particular report (which need to be picked). I think it should have some other solution.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any thing more from my end to get its resolution.

Comment: If everthing is fine then check @Dmitri T answer. You need to use "Save response to a file"

Answer (score 0):

JMeter will not "download" anything unless you explicitly "tell" it to store the response using i.e. [Save Responses to a file](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener. Add it as a child of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler which is supposed to download the file and configure like:

- Filename prefix: anything meaningful, i.e. `foo.csv`
- Tick `Don't add number to prefix`
- Tick `Don't add suffix`

  [image: JMeter Save Responses to a file configuration]

Once you do this and run your test JMeter will save the response as `foo.csv` file in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation. See [Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) article for comprehensive information on properly simulating file uploads and downloads using JMeter.

Comment: I have added the screenshots in the question for reference. Please add if anything is missing in the Save response to file listener or if there is any correction in Beanshell code.

Comment: Mainly i am stuck with the attached error in the jmeter log file. I have searched the error but icould not find its resolution. Please help.